# "Verifying backup..." step in Déjà Dup hangs

Tags: backup, deja-dup

The [Déjà Dup](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/DejaDup) Back Up process proceeds through the backup sequence. It reports "Uploading..." and then proceeds to "Verifying backup..." However, at "Verifying backup..." it seems to get suck. No progress is reported to the progress bar and no other activity is reported. The System Monitor does show a "deja-dup" process and a "duplicity" process but both are reported to be sleeping and show no CPU activity. No network activity is reported either.

Hitting "Cancel" does seem to cancel the backup. I am unsure how to debug this issue further. It is not clear where I could find additional logging or debug info.

Is there a method for debugging this phase of the backup process?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an issue as I also have this happening. You just have to give it time to perform that task.

I see this happening when the backup becomes too large, so I usually remove the old backup first and start afresh **but make sure you have:**

1. Uninterrupted power, and
2. Disable screen lock time out, as the screen must be kept alive.